# Html canvas 1600x1200 screen tearing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, windows-8

I've seen a couple of questions asking about this, but they're all over three years old and usually end by saying theres not much of a way around it yet, so im wondering if anything's changed.

I'm currently working on a game that draws onto a canvas using an interval that happens 60 times a second. It works great on my iphone and PC, which has a faily decent graphics card, but I'm now trying it on a Thinkcentre with intel i3 graphics, and I notice some huge screen tearing:
http://s21.postimg.org/h6c42hic7/tear.jpg - it's a little harder to notice as a still.

I was just wondering if there's any way to reduce that, or to easily enable vertical sync. If there isnt, is there somethingthat I could do in my windows 8 app port of the game?

Comment: That game looks badass

Comment: @cgatian thank you:) pilower.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using requestAnimationFrame (RAF)? RAF will v-sync but setTimeout/setInterval will not.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh920765

Also, since 30fps is adequate for your users to see smooth motion, how about splitting your 60fps into 2 alternating parts:

- "calculate/update" during one frame (no drawing)
- and then do all the drawing in the next frame.

And, get to know Chrome's Timeline tool.  This great little tool lets you analyze your code to discover where your code is taking the most time.  Then refactor that part of your code for high performance.

**[ Addition: More useful details about requestAnimationFrame ]**

Canvas does not paint directly to the display screen.  Instead, canvas "renders" to a temporary offscreen buffer.  “Rendering” means the process of executing canvas commands to draw on the offscreen  buffer.  This offscreen buffer will be quickly drawn to the actual display screen when the next screen refresh occurs.

Tearing occurs when the offscreen rendering process is only partially complete when the offscreen buffer is drawn on the actual display screen during refresh.

setInterval does not attempt to coordinate rendering with screen refresh.  So, using setInterval to control animation frames will occasionally produce tearing .

requestAnimationFrame (RAF) attempts to fix tearing by generating frames only between screen refreshes (a process called vertical synching).   The typical display refreshes about 60 times per second (that’s every 16 milliseconds).

**With requestAnimationFrame (RAF):**

- If the current frame is not fully rendered before the next refresh,
- RAF will delay the painting of the current frame until the next screen refresh.
- This delay reduces tearing.

So for you, RAF will likely help your tearing problem, but it also introduces another problem.

You must decide how to handle your physics processing:

- Keep it in a separate process—like setInterval.
- Move it into requestAnimationFrame.
- Move it into web-workers (the work is done on a background thread separate from the UI thread).

*Keep physics in a separate setInterval.*

This is a bit like riding 2 trains with 1 leg on each—very difficult!  You must be sure that all aspects of the physics are always in a valid state because you never know when RAF will read the physics to do rendering.  You will probably have to create a “buffer” of your physics variables so they always are in a valid state.

*Move physics into RAF:*

If you can both calculate physics and render within the 16ms between refreshes, this solution is ideal.  If not, your frame may be delayed until the next refresh cycle.  This results in 30fps which is not terrible since the eye still perceives lucid motion at 30fps.  Worst case is that the delay sometimes occurs and sometimes not—then your animation may appear jerky. So the key here is to spread the calculations as evenly as possible between refresh cycles.

*Move physics into web workers*

Javascript is single-threaded.  Both the UI and calculations must run on this single thread.  But you can use web workers which run physics on a separate thread.  This frees up the UI thread to concentrate on rendering and painting.  But you must coordinate the background physics with the foreground UI.

Good luck with your game :)

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

This is probably a good starting point for implementing requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @bvx89: Agreed...and I also like this classic link which further explains why RAF is often better than setInterval/setTimeout: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/

Comment: Great, but I don't quite get what you mean by calculate, I have an entirely seperate interval also running at 60 frames that does all the game calculations like physics ect, I did this so I could easier change the draw rate without effecting the game

Comment: Did you check out requestAnimationFrame(RAF)?  The RAF structure might help with your tearing because the callback is called relative to browser refreshes.    By "calculate" I do indeed mean any physics calculations that must be done before rendering (before drawing).  I've updated my answer with more details about RAF.

Comment: OP: Web workers + typed arrays (as they can be passed as references rather than copies) will probably be a good path to take the physics calculations.

Comment: Thanks A lot, I switched my interval to RAF and left my calculations on their own interval, except I'm still experiencing the same, if not more tearing, I've had plans to switch to using a worker (once I get a little more used to them, would that work?